# How to get a string consisting of all unique characters of original string preserving order?

Tags: java, string

Given a String input:

```
aaabbbcccdddeee
```

Output should be:

```
abcde
```

How I made this program?

Given an input String, I have sorted the characters of this String in ascending order using bubble sort [no need for efficient algorithm now] and then removed duplicates.

But the problem is that I cannot apply this approach on a string string like `bbkjhiaa`, as it changes the order of my original string.

I need to code this using concepts of array and string only.

```
class SingleOccurence
{
    static String singleoccurence(String p)
    {
        char current = ch[0];
        boolean found = false; //what is the use of boolean variable 
        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) 
        {
            if (current == ch[i] && !found) 
            {
                found = true;  
            }
            else if (current != ch[i])
            {
                System.out.print(current);
                current = ch[i];
                found = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(current);
        String s4=new String(ch);
        return s4;   
    }
    public static void main(String s[])
    {  
        String s1=new String("qwwnniitootiinn");
        String s6=SortingDemo.bubble1(s1);
        String s5=singleoccurence(s6);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need substring or a string with distinct characters?. Like @RealSkeptic says, you are not doing a subString here

Comment: @TheLostMind Yes,I need a SubString with different characters

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes,I need a SubString with different characters

Comment: @javaCoderMakeSimple - So you need all *unique characters of the string*?. if string is `aaabbbcccdddeee` , then  *valid* substrings would be `aaabbb` or `bcccd` etc. NOT `abcde`

Comment: @TheLostMind i think then i don't need a substring then.Ionly want to print abcde or bkjhia non duplicate elements in the string

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes.It is incorrect i think then i don't need a substring then.Ionly want to print abcde or bkjhia non duplicate elements in the string.

Comment: What output do you expect for `xyxz`? `xyxz` or `xyz`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed sorting the string will not be possible because this could change the input.

What you need to do is **put the whole string in an array and then iterate over the array from begin to end**. Always **remember the last visited value and compare with it**. If the value we are considering now is the same as the previous, then skip it, else display it.

```
public static String deDuplicate(char[] inpt) {
    Set<Character> already_seen_chars = new HashSet<Character>();
    String result = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < inpt.length; i++) {
        if(!already_seen_chars.contains(inpt[i])) { // Is the character already contained in the set?
            result += Character.toString(inpt[i]);
            already_seen_chars.add(inpt[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "ttttteeeeesssstttt";
    System.out.println(deDuplicate(test.toCharArray()));
}
```

Input : *qwwnniitootiinn*, Output : *qwnito*

Note that the performance is also better as before, O(n) instead of O(n^2) (where n is the string's length).

EDIT : If you are not allowed to use the Set datastructure, you can replace `mySet.contains(...)` by a for loop which iterates over the string and checks for the character.

This gives :

```
public static String deDuplicate(String input) {
    char[] inpt = input.toCharArray();
    String result = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < inpt.length; i++) {
        if(!contains(inpt, inpt[i], i)) { // Is the character already contained in the set?
            result += Character.toString(inpt[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

And the `contains` function is :

```
public static boolean contains(char[] inpt, char c, int maxIndex) {
    for(int i = 0; (i < inpt.length) && (i < maxIndex); i++) {
        if(inpt[i] == c)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Note that this affects the performance! The `for` loop in `deDuplicate` now calls `contains` which also contains a `for` loop. Hence resulting in a O(n^2) performance.

Comment: Why your code is not getting correct output for the input tttjeessttj? It should be ttjes.

Comment: The code I gave you is to eliminate duplicate characters (as noted in the question's title). So `tttjeessttj` after eliminating the duplicate characters, results in `tjestj` and not `ttjes` , here is still a duplicate (`tt`) and the order of the characters changed... ? But the question stated you wanted to preserve the sequence of the original string. If this is not what you want, please be clearer on the desired behaviour.

Comment: We have to remove Duplicity in the string.So if the character is already occurred u need not print the characters in other words print the unique characters in the string.Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: @javaCoderMakeSimple I edited it, now it is not comparing with the previous character anymore but with all visited characters, to filter out duplicate characters. Note that `tjestj` now results in `tjes` , but not `ttjes` as `t` occurs 2 times in the latter.

Comment: You are using a `HashSet`, which is a good idea, but the OP said the requirement is to use only strings and arrays.

Comment: He could replace `already_seen_chars.contains(inpt[i])` by a for loop that iterates from the first character in the string until it encounters character `inpt[i]` or until it encounters the i'th character. I will edit my post with that.

Answer (score 1):

This would work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    String s = "aaabbbcccdddeee";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(.)(?=.*\\1)",""));
}
```

O/P :

```
abcde
```

For input : bbkjhiaa
O/P : bkjhia

Comment: His assignment requires the use of only strings and arrays, I think using regex is not in that domain.

Comment: @RealSkeptic - Well, I am trying to do my bit here :)

Comment: Yes Since i am practicing question on string and array.It would be helpful if the approach could be using these concepts only.Also, For the test case which no one is pointing is For example i have input aabbccddaabb i want output as abcd.

Comment: @javaCoderMakeSimple - My code handles your case.. Also, if you need only String concepts, then you probably need a loop with `subString()`, `contains()` or `indexOf()` :) (Not to add - *and lot of patience* :P)

Comment: @LostMind Ya true i will try my best.Thanx for the hint :) :P

Comment: Your code doesn't actually cover the case he gave, it's returning `cdab` for that instead of `abcd`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to de-duplicate data is to use a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), because [sets only allow each object in them to appear once](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28abstract_data_type%29).

Example:

```
String onlyUniqueCharacters(String s) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    final Set<Character> uniqueChars = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        final char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (uniqueChars.add(c) sb.append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
 }
```

Comment: set does not preserve order

Comment: Sets don't preserve order, but the code here does - it looks at each character in order, and copies it to the order-preserving `StringBuilder`, but only if that character has not been seen before, according to the Set